# If statement not working properly in Hanoi Tower solution

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

In this code to find the solution to the Hanoi Tower problem I set N (number of disks) to 4, as an example and when I run it prints out this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HanoiTower {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose number of disks? ");
    N= in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    towers(N,0,1,2);        
  }

  static void towers(int disks, int a,int b, int spare){ 

    if (disks==1){
      System.out.println("Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 ");
    }
    else{
      towers(disks-1, a,spare,b);
      System.out.printf("Move disk %d from stack %d to stack %d ", disks, a, b);
      towers(disks-1,spare,b,a);
    }
  }
}
```

My doubt is why does it print in first place the if statement?

```
 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 0 to stack 2 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 3 from stack 0 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 2 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 4 from stack 0 to stack 2 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 1 to stack 0 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 3 from stack 1 to stack 2 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 0 to stack 2 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 5 from stack 0 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 2 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 3 from stack 2 to stack 0 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 1 to stack 0 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 4 from stack 2 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 0 to stack 2 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 3 from stack 0 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
 Move disk 2 from stack 2 to stack 1 Move disk 1 from 1 to 2
```

Comment: The method is called recursively.

Comment: Print your `disks` variable inside method `towers()` before the if condition.

Comment: Minor comment, but `N` is not a typical Java variable name. Variable names should be `camelCase`, so `n` would be more appropriate. Also your `towers` method could be `private`, since it isn't used outside your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `towers` recurses until `disks` is equal to 1. You could log the value of disks at the beginning like

```
static void towers(int disks, int a, int b, int spare) {
    System.out.printf("Disks = %d%n", disks);
    if (disks == 1) {
        System.out.println("Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 ");
    } else {
        towers(disks - 1, a, spare, b);
        System.out.printf("Move disk %d from stack %d to stack %d ", disks,
                a, b);
        towers(disks - 1, spare, b, a);
    }
}
```

And you can see why you get the output you do. Also, it's a bad idea to close a `Scanner` around `System.in` (once you close `System.in`, you can't open it again).

Answer (score 1):

It is always coming to the else block first and doing the recursion as you designed. So the output with some print statements will clarify it...

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int N;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose number of disks? ");
    N= in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Printing the N..."+N);
    towers(N,0,1,2);

}

static void towers(int disks, int a,int b, int spare){
    System.out.println("Printing the disks..."+disks);

    if (disks==1){
        System.out.println("Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 ");}
    else{
        towers(disks-1, a,spare,b);
        System.out.printf("Move disk %d from stack %d to stack %d ", disks, a, b);
        towers(disks-1,spare,b,a);
    }
    }
```

Output:

```
Printing the N...4
Printing the disks...4
Printing the disks...3
Printing the disks...2
Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 2 from stack 0 to stack 1 Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 3 from stack 0 to stack 2 Printing the disks...2
Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 2 from stack 1 to stack 2 Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 4 from stack 0 to stack 1 Printing the disks...3
Printing the disks...2
Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 2 from stack 2 to stack 0 Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 3 from stack 2 to stack 1 Printing the disks...2
Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2 
Move disk 2 from stack 0 to stack 1 Printing the disks...1
Move disk 1 from 1 to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` works correctly, you can be sure about it. If you call the method with any number greater than 1, it will call itself recursively in line `towers(disks-1, a,spare,b);` until the number is 1. Then it will print the first message.